# animate() moves up container but content is not scrollable

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate, toggle

I am making a website at the moment which consists of three parts:

- A div which contains some text and the background image
- A button which toggles a div which contains some logos and links to other websites
- A sticky footer

To toggle the second div I made it work with the `slideToggle()` function of jQuery and the div with the texts moves up with the `animate(bottom: 200px;)` function, but it's not working how I want it to, because it moves the text and background image out of the viewport without being able to scroll up. Because of this it cuts off half of the website and just when I close the second div with the links the background and text moves back in to the viewport.

Any idea on how to solve this issue?

```js
var flag = true;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".toggle-partner").click(function() {
    $(".partner").slideToggle(1000);
    $("span", this).toggleClass("glyphicon glyphicon-menu-up glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down");

    if (flag) {
      $(".background").animate({
        bottom: "200px"
      }, 1000, "linear");
      flag = false;
    } else {
      $(".background").animate({
        bottom: "0px"
      }, 1000, "linear");
      flag = true;
    }
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  font-family: 'Comfortaa', sans-serif;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.background {
  background: url(bg4.png) #e8f1d5 no-repeat left top;
  background-size: contain;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}


/* -------- TEXT FORMATIERUNG ----- */

.text {
  text-align: right;
  padding-top: 5%;
  padding-right: 5%;
}

#partner-toggle {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

.partner {
  padding: 15px;
  display: flex;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: rgb(235, 237, 249);
  /* Farbcode #ebedf9 */
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
  height: 150px;
}

.partner img {
  margin: 10;
}

.toggle-partner {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #c1e1f0;
  width: 300px;
  border-radius: 15px 15px 0 0;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 10px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  align-content: center;
  border: none;
}


/* ------ FOOTER ------- */

footer {
  height: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #46a4d2;
  padding: 5px;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main>
  <div class="container-fluid background">
    <div class="container-fluid text">
      <p>TEXT<p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="partner-toggle" class="container-fluid">
    <button class="toggle-partner">Kooperationspartner &nbsp; &nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-up"></span></button>
    <div class="partner container-fluid">
      Some Content
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
<footer class="container-fluid"></footer>
```